# how to use sympy library to create a leakey Relu function [For implementation]

Tags: python

the main problem is that how to use **sympy library** to **create a Leakey Relu function**.
Now I can use NumPy to construct the Leakey Relu function. I found three methods to do it as the following codes shown

```
import numpy as np                                                 

x = np.random.normal(size=[1, 5])

# first approach                           
leaky_way1 = np.where(x > 0, x, x * 0.01)                          

# second approach                                                                   
y1 = ((x > 0) * x)                                                 
y2 = ((x <= 0) * x * 0.01)                                         
leaky_way2 = y1 + y2

# Third approach   
def leaky_relu(arr):
    alpha = 0.1
 
    return np.maximum(alpha*arr, arr)
```

But I **need to calculate the intergral of variables's leakey relu**, so I use the sympy library to construct the leakey relu first.

but I have no idea in **compute the judgment used to determine whether an element is greater than zero** such as ***np.where(x > 0),(x > 0),and np.maximum()***

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leaky ReLu is given as $f(x)= \begin{cases} \alpha x & ,x\leq 0 \\x & ,otherwise \end{cases} \qquad ,with \quad\alpha = 0.01$

So you can determine the antiderivative, to calculate integrals as: $F(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{\alpha}{2} x^2 & ,x\leq 0 \\\frac{1}{2} x^2 & ,otherwise \end{cases}$

You can implement the antiderivative with numpys where() function as well:

```
leaky_relu = np.where(x > 0, x, x * 0.01)  
leaky_relu_integral = np.where(x > 0, x * x / 2, x * x * 0.01 / 2)
```

For sympy (**V1.8**) you can implement leaky ReLu using the piecewise function:

```
from sympy import *  
x = Symbol('x')
leaky_relu = Piecewise((0.01*x,x<0),(x, x>=0))

# test leaky relu
leaky_relu.subs(x, 5)  # gives 5
leaky_relu.subs(x, -5) # gives -0.05

# integrate leaky relu
integrate(leaky_relu, x)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I think the main problem is how to use the sympy library to create a leakey relu function. I post another question [how to calculate the double integral of the following function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/540106/185883) to show you more details.

Comment: I added how to implement leaky ReLu as sympy function and integrate it

Comment: thank you. I tried your codes today. and I also found that we should use leaky_relu.subs(x, 5)